# What is the best way to say format is mm/dd/yyyy - but in the local format?

Tags: excel, datetime

Excel appears to not have this (unless I missed it), but we're getting demand for it. And since we try to match Excel for the cell formatting syntax, I'd like to add this in in a way that makes sense.

So any suggestions on how to specify that you want a short/medium/long date/time/datetime formatted in the local layout? In other words I can spec so that in the US I get mm/dd/yy and in Germany yyyy mm dd.

thanks - dave

Comment: Under Format Cells, for Date and Time, there is a Locale (location) dropdown.  Does that not work for you?  If you're looking for VBA help, this question may point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can use the **asterisk** in the **Cell Format menu** to choose you cell to display depending on the current system regional settings.

For instance : `*06/30/2011` would display differently depending on your system regional settings :

- 06/30/2011 for US or UK (for instance)
- 30/06/2011 for France (for instance)

See [here](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/) for more information.

Comment: Ah, proof again that I don't know everything. :P Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Select the column/row or cell you want to format:

```
right button > Format cells > Custom > Type
```

There is some examples in the box below, some examples are:

d-mmm-yy -> The single d stands for day of month, without leading zeros
dd-mm-yyyy
yyyy-mm-dd
d/mmm/-yy -> mmm stands for name of the month
dd/mm/yyyy -> You can also specify the separator
yyyy/mm/dd

And so on.