# How to format the date format as system date format in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

It is require to change the date column in excel as system date format.

if the system date format will be `mm/dd/yyyy`

In excel sheet i need to change it as `mm/dd/yyyy`
How to change it through VBA Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the date format of cell to the regional (Windows) settings this way:

1. Select the cells you want to change
2. Right-click > Format Cells...
3. Tab "Number", choose "Date"
4. Choose a date begining with an asterisk `*`: `*05/13/2011`

More information on this SO thread: [What is the best way to say format is mm/dd/yyyy - but in the local format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539202/what-is-the-best-way-to-say-format-is-mm-dd-yyyy-but-in-the-local-format)

**[EDIT]** With VBA you can do

```
Sub test()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

`m/d/yyyy` represents the regional settings as described above

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But, When the date is less than 12 it is not working, it remains the same like 10/09/2011.