# How to change the locale of a formatted date?

Tags: vba, locale, date-format

I want to retrieve today's date in a specific format with English month name.

I'm using 
`Format(DateValue(Now), "dd-mmm-yyyy")`,
which gives me
`05-cze-2013`,
which is in Polish. What I want to get is
`05-Jan-2013`.

I am only interested in a VBA solution. Please also provide a way to set the locale back to the original, also using VBA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not very difficult...

```
Sub VBA_Dates_Format()
    Cells.Clear
    Range("A1").Value = Now
    Range("A2").Value = Now
    ' Polish
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[$-415]d mmm yy;@"
    ' English UK
    Range("A2").NumberFormat = "[$-809]d mmm yy;@"
End Sub
```

I have achieved this by recording and modifying a macro to fit the criteria.

---

[Further reading available here](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/)

Comment: **Mehow**, that's really impressive. I have not seen this trick done before. Do you have a link for further reading? I'd really like to understand how you accomplilshed this.

Comment: @tbur ive recorded and edited a macro, but also I have provided a useful link in case you wanted to dig deeper

Comment: How can I do this with a String variable? `Dim myDate As String: myDate = Format(DateValue(Now), "[$-409]mmmm yyyy")` doesn't work, the month is still in english (my OS language)...

Comment: I know this is old, but hopefully this helps more people understand locale codes. the `-409' represents the en-US language. Nothing, more and nothing less. using this defines what variables you need to use for linking year, day, month etc...

For a more complete list on Locale Codes, and how to change actual language, and or number text then check out this answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134729/what-does-the-130000-in-excel-locale-code-130000-mean/54540455#54540455

Answer (score 2):

Try use

```
 Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "[$-th-TH,107]d mmm yyyy;@")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clean VBA but it's a way to get localized formatted date in string. Something that Format function can't do.

```
With Range("$A$1")
    .NumberFormat = "[$-809]dd mmmm"
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
    tmp = .Text
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = CStr(tmp)
End With
```

More info about localized formatting i great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/899290 from Ian Boyd