# How can I change the language for elements of an array in VBA?

Tags: vba

My language settings are German. In a macro, I assign a 1450x20 Range to an array to speed up computation. One column of the array contains dates, formatted as "MMM JJ", as well as strings. I want to change the dates to strings that use the "MMM JJ" format. However, when I tried to use Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(element_of_array, "MMM JJ"), VBA automatically uses American, so for example, instead of "Dez 14", I get "Dec 14".

I haven't found a way to change this and would appreciate help.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Please start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16935265/14094617)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that - I did try doing it that way with the german code [$402], but this resulted in "402" being added to the string - I assume it doesn't work if it isn't done within a cell, but to the element of an array?

Comment: No, no! Do all the operations on the array as before. Just after inserting it into the sheet, apply .NumberFormat to the entire date column - don't convert dates, just format the result.

Comment: After that, go through the column `For each oCell in` and replace `oCell.Value = "'" & oCell.Text` (for 1450 cells it will be quickly)

Comment: Make your array store actual `Date` values (not strings!), and then use a `Range.NumberFormat` format string to format the dates as needed in their destination cells.

Comment: @JohnSUN I think `allTheCells.Value = allTheCells.Text` should work too, without a need for a loop.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have encountered a situation several times when `allTheCells.Text` gave an error. It always works for one cell, but not for a range.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon In addition, we need to add an apostrophe so that Excel does not helpfully convert the text to a date again.

Comment: @JohnSUN tbh I just stick with `Range.Value`, the `.Text` being largely irrelevant for programmatic purposes. And you are correct, the `.Value = .Value` thing was about replacing a formula with its value, and I somehow got confused here :)