When checkboxes are ticked, captions should be put in a comma separated string and be placed into an array
I want when checkboxes are checked, its captions be put in a comma separated string and be placed into an array.
Checkboxes 1 to 12 will be for the Profits column.
Checkboxes 13 to 24 will be for the Capital column.
The code where I would like to insert the code for the checkboxes.
Private Sub SUBMIT_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String, arr, c As Range, id
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Employee ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Loader File")
        Set c = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '##start adding here
        arr = Split(TextBox1.Value, ",") '##split on comma to get an array
        
            For i = 21 To 35 Step 2                           '## loop over comboboxes
            dataItem = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value '## read combo values...
            schedule = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & (i + 1)).Value
            If Len(dataItem) > 0 Then             '## any value selected?
            
        For Each id In arr               '##loop over the array
             c.Resize(1, 30).Value = Array(Trim(id), TextBox2.Value, TextBox3.Value, TextBox4.Value, TextBox5.Value, TextBox6.Value, TextBox7.Value, TextBox8.Value, _
                                     ComboBox7.Value, ComboBox8.Value, ComboBox9.Value, ComboBox10.Value, ComboBox11.Value, _
                                     ComboBox12.Value, ComboBox13.Value, ComboBox14.Value, ComboBox15.Value, ComboBox16.Value, _
                                     ComboBox17.Value, ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox2.Value, ComboBox3.Value, ComboBox4.Value, _
                                     ComboBox5.Value, ComboBox6.Value, ComboBox18.Value, ComboBox19.Value, ComboBox20.Value, dataItem, schedule, Profits, Capital)
             
            Set c = c.Offset(1)          '##next output row
                Next id
            End If
        Next i

        MsgBox "Information Loaded", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Notification"
        Unload Me
    End If
    
End Sub

This is my draft code for checkboxes, but I am not sure if this is correct and how it will be placed in my current code.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String, arr, c As Range, id
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Employee ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Loader File")
        Set c = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '##start adding here
        arr = Split(CheckBox1.Caption, ",")
        
        For Each xcontrol In Me.Controls
    
        If TypeName(xcontrol) = "CheckBox" And xcontrol.Value = True Then
        
        CheckBox1.Value = "Jan"
        CheckBox2.Value = "Feb"
        CheckBox3.Value = "Mar"
        CheckBox4.Value = "Apr"
        CheckBox5.Value = "May"
        CheckBox6.Value = "Jun"
        CheckBox7.Value = "Jul"
        CheckBox8.Value = "Aug"
        CheckBox9.Value = "Sep"
        CheckBox10.Value = "Oct"
        CheckBox11.Value = "Nov"
        CheckBox12.Value = "Dec"
        
        
        For i = 1 To 12 Step 2                           '## loop over comboboxes
        Profits = Me.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value '## read combo values...
        If Len(Dividend) > 0 Then             '## any value selected?

        For Each id In arr               '##loop over the array
            c.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(Trim(id), Dividend)
            Set c = c.Offset(1)          '##next output row
                Next id
            End If
        Next i

        MsgBox "Time Series Attributes Loaded", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Notification"
        Unload Me
    End If

End Sub

Sample userform.

When the user ticks one of the boxes, its caption should be put into a comma separated string.


"For checkboxes 1 to 24 it will be for the column Profits and for Checkboxes 13 to 24 it will be for column Capital" are you sure that's correct? "1 to 24" and "13 to 24" are overlapping.

Hello Tim, apologies. That should be 1-12 for profits

its caption will be placed into an array and will be separated by comma Do you want to have an array or a comma seperated string? And how it is related with SUBMIT_Click?

Hello Taller. What happens is when the user click the submit button in the userform, all of the data will be transferred into specific columns of the “bulk loader file” sheet. The checkboxes represents each month ranging from Jan to Dec. what I want to happen is when the user ticked the corresponding checkboxes, its captions will be on  comma separated string and will be placed into an array.

So you can’t re-use the exact same For loop

I’m sorry do you mean that will not be possible?

No I mean think about what that loop actually does. In this case your checkboxes are not alternating like your textboxes are, so either follow the same convention as the textbox naming, or change the loop.  If you don't know how your current code works, you'll never be able to fix/change it.

I'm sorry this is my first time working with checkboxes. I tried to revise the code for the profits column and I'm getting error message saying "For without next".

Checkboxes have a values of either True or False, so this for example CheckBox1.Value = "Jan" can't work, and it's not really clear what you want to do there.  A screenshot of your form might help here, along with an example of the output you want to create in the worksheet.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Based on the file you shared and discussion in Chat:
Private Sub SUBMIT_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String, arrId, c As Range, id, arr
    Dim profits As String, capitals As String, i As Long, col As Collection
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Lipper ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
        Exit Sub 'cleaner to exit here - reduces nesting level of code below
    End If
    
    'OK to write to sheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Loader File")
    Set c = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '##start adding here
    arrId = Split(TextBox1.Value, ",") '##split on comma to get an array
    
    '## collect any checked profit and capital months
    For i = 1 To 12 'if checkboxes are checked then add month name to appropriate string
        If Me.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value = True Then        ' 1 to 12 <TW> True not "True"....
            AddWithComma profits, MonthName(i)
        End If
        If Me.Controls("Checkbox" & (12 + i)).Value = True Then ' 13 to 24
            AddWithComma capitals, MonthName(i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    '## check Asset Collection Schedule for any selections
    Set col = New Collection
    For i = 21 To 35 Step 2                           '## loop over comboboxes
        dataItem = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value '## read combo values...
        schedule = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & (i + 1)).Value
        If Len(dataItem) > 0 Then col.Add Array(dataItem, schedule) '## add any selected pairs to collection
    Next i
    If col.Count = 0 Then col.Add Array("", "") 'nothing was selected, so add one set of blank values
    
    'write out records
    For Each id In arrId               '##loop over the array
        For Each arr In col            '...and the collection
            c.Resize(1, 32).Value = _
               Array(Trim(id), TextBox2.Value, TextBox3.Value, TextBox4.Value, TextBox5.Value, TextBox6.Value, _
                  TextBox7.Value, TextBox8.Value, ComboBox7.Value, ComboBox8.Value, ComboBox9.Value, ComboBox10.Value, _
                  ComboBox11.Value, ComboBox12.Value, ComboBox13.Value, ComboBox14.Value, ComboBox15.Value, ComboBox16.Value, _
                  ComboBox17.Value, ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox2.Value, ComboBox3.Value, ComboBox4.Value, _
                  ComboBox5.Value, ComboBox6.Value, ComboBox18.Value, ComboBox19.Value, ComboBox20.Value, _
                  arr(0), arr(1), profits, capitals)
         
            Set c = c.Offset(1)          '##next output row
        Next arr
    Next id
    
    MsgBox "Time Series Attributes Loaded", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Notification"
    Unload Me
    
End Sub

''Return month name for month# `monthNum`
Function MonthName(monthNum As Long) As String
    MonthName = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", _
                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")(monthNum - 1) 'zero-based array
End Function

'utility sub for adding to a string as a comma-separated value
Sub AddWithComma(ByRef msg As String, addThis As String)
    msg = msg & IIf(Len(msg) > 0, ",", "") & addThis
End Sub


Hello Tim, I have added the code for the checkboxes to the the rest of the code that I have for the userform.  The codes seem to run however, there is no data reflecting on the sheet.

See edit above - added " = True" when checking the checkbox values

@TimWilliams Just for fun: Instead of defining a months array explicitly by names (using Excel) you could return the function result also as evaluation: MonthName = [Index(Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),"mmm"), monthNum)]

@TimWilliams ... the correct return code in my above comment should be: MonthName = Evaluate("Index(Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),""mmm"")," & monthnum & ")")  as the changing monthnum isn't part of the tabular Excel formula :-;

@TM  - I had considered Format(DateSerial(2024, monthNum, 1),"mmm") but decided to opt for the locale-independent fixed values....

@TimWilliams afaik the above evaluation will return only the English date abbreviations

No I think it uses the OS locale - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934582/how-to-change-the-locale-of-a-formatted-date

@TimWilliams Thx for feedback to my somewhat misleading comment -  I referred to the corrected code in my own comment: a) the formula evaluation Evaluate("Index(Text(Date(0,Column(A:L),1),""mmm"")," & monthnum & ")") returns en-us date abbreviations, whereas b) VBA's Format(DateSerial(2024, monthNum, 1),"mmm") which you considered first will return either the local equivalents or the explicitly addressed formats via [$-nnn] pattern.
