# How to parse locale(Australia) specific date format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting, country-codes

I am trying to parse the date format `[[$-C09]dd\-mmm\-yy;@]` using `SimpleDateFormat` with default Locale. But it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'C'
```

How to parse the date using this date format? `C09` in the date format denotes the Australian country code.

**My Code snippet:**

```
String pattern = "[$-C09]dd-mmm-yy;@";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern,Locale.getDefault());
```

**Source:**

Please refer the [SO answers below for Country wide codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409).

Comment: Use single quotes to quote random strings. Described [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).