# TODAY and WEEKDAY values differents on 2 computers

Tags: vba, date, weekday

I made a script allowing to automatically add the stats of the week, but I have an issue to display the date of the Monday of the current week.

Given `2017-06-26`, on my laptop I get `2017-06-26` which is correct, but on the other laptop I get `2017-06-03`...

How to solve this? I tried to put the same language on both machines, but same problem. Furthermore, when I use `TODAY` and `WEEKDAY` independently, the values of the 2nd computer are the same as for the first computer, its only occurs when I want to calculate the date of the first day of the current week.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Range("A" & i + 5).Formula = "=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1"  '"week "[$-en-US]mmmm jj"th"
Range("A" & i + 5).NumberFormat = """week ""[$-en-US]mmmm dd""th"""
```

Comment: I already said it in my first message :
First laptop : 
Result : 26 june
Expectd : 26 june

Second laptop :
Result : 3 june
Expected : 26 june

Same code on both laptop

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify, and retracted my votes. Note that I assumed the incorrect date value you are getting is `2017-06-03`; please confirm you meant "June 3rd" as such.

Comment: My result is "week June 03th", but only as a result of the `NumberFormat`. Without that, the date appears correctly.

Comment: If you look at the number format that's actually applied, you probably see something like: `"week "[$-F6EFC]mmmm dd"th"`.  There seems to be something wrong with your format string.

Comment: If I use a format string as `"week "mmm dd"th"` then the results are `week June 26th`.

Comment: @DavidZemens correct. It's the `[$-en-US]` that's messing it up. `mmm` would output `Jun` though ;-)

Comment: If you're trying to force EN-US dates, use the *format code* [$409] instead of `[$-en-US]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409

Comment: @DavidZemens looks like you have answer material there :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug probably just gonna dupe it

Comment: though I'm not sure *why* it's a problem on one machine but not another, I suspect it has to do with locale settings.

Comment: My understanding is that this is just a misuse of a formatting predicate; "if culture is en-US then format this way, otherwise.... (no alternative specified)" - pretty sure OP would get correct output all the time without it. @DavidZemens I already retracted a close vote, can't dupe-hammer - it's all yours!

Comment: Ahhhh @Mat'sMug so you're saying the discrepancy appears only *if* the user locale is en-US, but otherwise the formatting condition isn't applied?  That would make sense then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148063/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-david-zemens).