# How to name an excel sheet in english

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to name my excel sheet in English format. My system settings are in German and i can't change that. I need to get the previous month name in english. I used the below code and formula.

I also tried using custom date settings for one cell and assign the cell value to sheet name.But nothing working. Help me

```
Sub name()
ActiveSheet.Name = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "MMMM")
End Sub

Choose(MONTH(TODAY())-1, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY())-1;DAY(TODAY()));"MMMM")
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `Select Case`?

Comment: I see there is a solution below.  I just wanted to point out that in your formula you are subtracting 1 from the value of the month.  This is problematic in general for January as your result will be zero.  You need a way to make it 12 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ActiveSheet.Name = Application.Text(DateAdd("M", -1, Now),"[$-409]MMMM")
```

`[$-409]` forces english names for day and month names (but it seems to be ignored by `Format`).
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/899290/7599798

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly