# What does the $ sign mean in TEXT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found an excel formula that transforms calendar dates into Chinese lunar dates:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[$-130000]d/m/yyyy")
```

Say A1 is

```
08/12/2018
```

The output of the formula is

```
2/11/2018
```

How does this work? What is `$`? What is `$-130000`? The [MS's help article on `TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) does not mention this.

What formula can I use to do the reverse calculation, i.e. from lunar calendar to solar calendar? `$+130000` does not work.

---

### Update

I just came across [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409), which says [$-xxxx] is some locale code, which makes perfect sense to me. However, I cannot find any source says what locale 130000 represents.

Comment: The place where it should be explained is https://support.office.com/en-us/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5, but it is not there either. If you put `[$-130000]d/m/yyyy` in the cell's custom format box, Excel transforms it to `[$-,13]d/m/yyyy`, and that indeed gives the same result as the original.

Comment: @GSerg looks like `$-` indicates some sort of encoding/decoding.

Comment: Also Excel converts `[$-13F800]d/m/yyyy` to `[$-x-sysdate,13]d/m/yyyy`, and `[$-13F400]d/m/yyyy` to `[$-x-systime,13]d/m/yyyy`...

Comment: From https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-dates-displayed-in-different-languages we see that Excel can display dates in "different languages" where language ID is taken from "[$-ID]..."

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин yes, but what locale or language ID does 130000 represents? I can't find any reference.

Comment: Really I could not clarify full list of possible identifiers, if it is missing in official sources. Let MS developers answer... But the question was about the **$ sign meaning**.

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин That is quite true. In that sense, I just answered my own question in update lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer about what does [$-130000] represent then check out my other answer here.

[What does the 130000 in Excel locale code [$-130000] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134729/what-does-the-130000-in-excel-locale-code-130000-mean/54540455#54540455)

I am not certain how to do a reverse conversion. If you try to do the reverse of the above function, which would be...

`=TEXT(A1, "[$-1010409]d/m/yyyy")`

But this simply takes the presented date, and converts it to the stated format (i.e. it sees whatever in "A1" as a Gregorian date already)

Comment: So how should these IDs be included in parsing correctly into DateTime object?