# Forcing US Currency (or other country) in Cell

Tags: excel, vba, currency, number-formatting

I'm hoping this is an easy one.
I'm using `Range.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"` to format a cell as US currency. But when our users in Japan open the workbook, they see it in Yen `¥` instead. I'm assuming because windows knows they are regionalized to Japan.
Is there a way to force it to stay US so there isn't any confusion?

Thank you

Comment: "USD #,##0.00"? just an idea.

Comment: Thanks, but this just throws an error

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to test this in a different region, but try:

```
Range.NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00"
```

based on the [locale code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409) `[$-409]`.

Another version:

```
Range.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
```

Comment: Its already their weekend, so I'll have to wait until Monday (US) time to see if it works, but thank you.