# How do I meet the [$-409] requirement when entering data manually in spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, xlsx

I have a legacy spreadsheet (meaning I can't really modify it, and have no one to ask). I have it open in OpenOffice but I checked it in Excel and the same thing happens.

There are two date columns that have the user-defined format code **[$-409]DD-MMM-YYYY;@** (see screenshot).

The cells in these columns **will not accept any date format I've tried**. It says 'invalid value'.

I did some research here on Stack overflow:
[excel-number-format-what-is-409](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894805/excel-number-format-what-is-409)
so now I know the $=409 is a locale code.

So now my question is: **when entering data manually, how can I arrange my date input to satisfy that condition?**

[image: Screengrab from .XLSX file opened in OpenOffice]

Comment: Sounds like data validation is the cause not the number format.

Comment: How do I resolve that? I'm entering the data by-hand.

Comment: I'm not sure where it is in your Excel, in mine on the ribbon --> Data --> Data Validation. Make sure you have the column in question selected.

Comment: Oh! I'm just turning off validation! Huh! Thank you! (Not sure how to make a comment into Accepted Answer.)